# How to instantiate function types in golang?

Tags: go

I would like to instantiate a bunch of functions of the same type without having to duplicate their signature. I already have a function type describing that signature (`fancyFunc` below) and another function consuming arguments of that kind (`doFancyStuff` below). How would I make something like this work?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type fancyFunc func(a,b,c int) int

func doFancyStuff(f FancyFunc) int {
    // Do something special with f
    return 42
}

func main() {
    // This works but is rather tedious:
    f1 := func(a,b,c int) int { return a + b + c }

    // I would like to create them like this:
    f2 := fancyFunc{ return a * b * c }

    // Eventually, they are used like this:
    fmt.Println(doFancyStuff(f1))
    fmt.Println(doFancyStuff(f2))
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only do it as in the `f1` case, or by defining a normal function. there is nothing like the `f2` way. In C people do this with macros, but Go doesn't have a preprocessor (there are a few unofficial ones you can use).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a particular preprocessor you would recommend; is `go generate` capable of doing this? Or would you rather not recommend doing this at all? This would feel like creating a dialect of go.
Furthermore, why is this not possible? When I define a struct, I too can replace its name by its definition when instantiating.

Comment: I would just avoid it. What are you saving here, some typing? Since Go is very opinionated, whenever you find yourself rowing against the current, it's usually a signal that you're doing it wrong. Not that I'm saying Go is always right, but I've learned to just relax and follow the language's idioms.